# C#.NET except linq not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 lists of custom object `BiometricLog`: 
`uploadedLog`, `logsFromBiometric` and `logsToBeUploaded`.

All data that matches `uploadedLog` should be removed from `logsFromBiometric`, then stored to `logsToBeUploaded`.

I tried using this code: 
`logsToBeUploaded` = `logsFromBiometric.Except(uploadedLogs).ToList()` but it doesn't work. Am i Missing something or doing something wrong?

Here is my full block of code.

```
var uploadedLogs = GetUploadedLogs();
var logsFromBiometric = new List<BiometricLog>();
var logsToBeUploaded = new List<BiometricLog>();

int counter = 0;
foreach (XmlNode biometric in biometricElements)
{
    taskArray[counter] = Task<List<BiometricLog>>.Factory.StartNew(() => ConnectAndProcessBiometric(biometric));
    counter++;
}

Task.WaitAll(taskArray);

foreach (var taskitem in taskArray)
{
    logsFromBiometric.AddRange(taskitem.Result);
}

logsFromBiometric.RemoveAll(m => uploadedLogs.Contains(m));

logsToBeUploaded = logsFromBiometric.Except(uploadedLogs).ToList();
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work".

Comment: It doesn't show any error, but the result is just logsFromBiometric without removing the uploadedLogs.

Comment: what determines the equality between two log objects? once you decide that you need to override Equals and GetHashcode methods in your log class to implement that logic so that Except method can use your comparison instead of the default which compares references. duplicated question contains an example of that and if you search for it there are tens of other similar questions.

Comment: Aren't you already removing all `uploadedLogs` from `logsFromBiometric` in the penultimate line?

Comment: I'd suspect a bug in the `Equals` and/or `GetHashCode` methods of `BiometricLog`.

Comment: hi can you give me an example on how to make iequalitycomparer work?

Comment: public class BiometricLog
    {
        public int LogID { get; set; }
        public int BiometricID { get; set; }
        public DateTime LogDateTime { get; set; }
        public int TransactionType { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }